# atoi with ints and doubles

Tags: c++, double, int, atoi

Can I use atoi to convert a text input to a dialog box to a double?

I need to do a calculation on several double values that have been input using a dialog box. I only know of 'atoi' but is this for integers only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Boost is an option, [Boost.lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) is a popular approach for converting to and from string representations of numerical values, e.g.:

```
char const s[] = "1.2345";
try
{
  double d = boost::lexical_cast<double>(s);
  ...
}
catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast &)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar to atoi() there is `double atof ( const char * str )` that you can use
[Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atof/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the `atoi`, `atol`, `strtol` family :

http://www.fiveanddime.net/man-pages/strtol.3.html

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using C++ (not just C) then you can parse text into floats using stl's [std::istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::stringstream` as:

```
std::stringstream ss(text);
double value;
if ( !( ss >> value ) )
{
   std::cout << "error : text is not double" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `atoi` and `atof` are more or less broken; there's no way to do any error checking.  In most cases, the simplest solution would be to use `strtod`:

```
char* endPtr;
errno = 0;
value = strtod( input, &endPtr );
if ( errno != 0 || *skipSpaces( endPtr ) != '\0' )
    //  Illegal input, conversion failed.
```

(I'm generally a fan of `istringstream`, but in this case, it seems overkill.)